# Is there a way or tool that enables me to use linux like shell environment on top of windows?

Tags: linux, windows

Is there a way in which I can use linux command like  `ls -l`    on the window command prompt ? or maybe use powerful commands like `grep` on windows ?

Comment: Look at powershell. And yes, it's unrelated to programming (offtopic).

Comment: Agreed,  this really belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) will do what you're looking for

Comment: think cygwin is what I am looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[MinGW/MSys](http://www.mingw.org/) is a minimal unix environment.